# iSCSI: lsscsi lists device but fdisk does not

Tags: freebsd, zfs, iscsi

How do I make freebsd show initiators a mountable target from a zpool?

On a fresh install of FreeBSD 10.2 (hostname `bohr`) I made a zpool named `tank` with a single vdev which is 2 disks in a mirror; then I used zfs to make a 4GB volume (`images`). I set up an iSCSI LUN with no-authentication for the group and target (for testing) pointing at `images`. Linux, FreeBSD, and OS X initiators can discover the target and connect but none of them finds a volume that I can format or mount.

```
root@bohr:/tank/volumes # zfs list
NAME                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank                 4.13G   895G    96K  /tank
tank/volumes         4.13G   895G   100K  /tank/volumes
tank/volumes/images  4.13G   899G    64K  -
root@bohr:/tank/volumes # zpool status
  pool: tank
  state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada1    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada2    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

root@bohr:~ # cat /etc/ctl.conf
auth-group ag0 {
    chap house shortshortdress
}

portal-group pg0 {
    discovery-auth-group no-authentication
    listen 0.0.0.0
    listen [::]
} 

target iqn.2015-09.com.example:images {
    auth-group no-authentication
    portal-group pg0

    lun 0 {
        path /tank/volumes/images
        size 4G
    }
}
```

so, here's a representative linux initiator, note the absence of `/dev/sdd` in the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
niels@suse_linux:~> lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD1600AAJB-5 01.0  /dev/sda
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVD-ROM GDR8162B 0015  /dev/sr0
[1:0:1:0]    cd/dvd  _NEC     DVD+RW ND-1100A  10FD  /dev/sr1
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      TOSHIBA DT01ACA2 MX4O  /dev/sdb
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      TOSHIBA DT01ACA2 MX4O  /dev/sdc
[21:0:0:0]   disk    FREEBSD  CTLDISK          0001  /dev/sdd

niels@suse_linux:~> sudo /usr/sbin/fdisk -l
root's password:

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 159974776832 bytes, 312450736 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c3390

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     4208639     2103296   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2   *     4208640    46153727    20972544   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        46153728   312449023   133147648   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 2000.3 GB, 2000264691712 bytes, 3906766976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Results on OS X are similar, connection but nothing available to `diskutil`. I tried using the freebsd box as an initiator also, and it will make the connection, but still no device I can access. Back to bohr for another example of a connection made, but

```
root@bohr:~ # iscsictl -L
Target name                          Target portal    State
iqn.2015-09.com.example:images 192.168.1.148    Connected: da0
```

I followed the FreeBSD manual for zfs and iscsi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I needed to route my LUN through the special device /dev/zvol. So instead `path /tank/volumes/images` I needed `path /dev/zvol/tank/volumes/images`. And that was it.